# Unable to Decode Stream Image to Fragment

Tags: java, android, arrays

The Code Works perfectly but Im having problem with the Permission Denied but i already put READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on Android Manifest any idea. Already Tried this one [Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358582/unable-to-decode-stream-java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied)

[BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream - null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163444/bitmapfactory-unable-to-decode-stream-null)

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20201001_125759.jpg (Permission
> denied)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
    //Open phone gallery
    private void getImageFromGallery(){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Check if the intent was to pick image, was successful and an image was picked
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.the_grid_image_preview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Android version 6.0 or up, you need to ask for permissions in runtime:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

For this I use a nice wrapper called [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) which simplifies it and is really easy to use.

You can then write this function in your Fragment:

```kotlin
private fun checkFilePermissions(onPermissionGranted: () -> Unit) {
        Dexter.withActivity(activity)
            .withPermissions(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
            .withListener(object : BaseMultiplePermissionsListener() {
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(response: MultiplePermissionsReport) {
                    if (response.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        onPermissionGranted()
                    }
                }
            })
            .check()
    }
```

And in when you call your method `getImageFromGallery()` just invoke it like this:

```kotlin
...
checkFilePermissions {
    getImageFromGallery()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea , i can't implement the dexter but this one works but its the same function https://stackoverflow.com/a/39866945/14265294

Comment: Cool, glad I helped :)